# Tekton dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, tekton, tekton-pipelines

Got the following error, while trying to view tekton dashboard using the command `kubectl port-forward -n tekton-pipelines service/tekton-dashboard 9097:9097`

Error from server (NotFound): services "tekton-dashboard" not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, tekton-dashboard was not installed.

The issue was resolved by running the following command

`kubectl apply --filename https://storage.googleapis.com/tekton-releases/dashboard/latest/release-full.yaml`

(The above command will install the tekton dashboard with read/write mode)

If you wish to Dashboard in read-only mode please use this

`kubectl apply --filename https://storage.googleapis.com/tekton-releases/dashboard/latest/release.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to install tekton dashboard as below and then please check and btw please check namespace because ns is here `tekton-pipelines`

```
https://tekton.dev/docs/dashboard/install/
```